# blueimp gallery set indicator on by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using `blueimp gallery` http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/ as a `lightbox` in my website. Is there an easy way to keep the `indicator` on by default? Right now, after you open a gallery in a lightbox you need to click on an image for it to show `navigation buttons` and `indicator options`.

Answer (score 24):

Add `blueimp-gallery-controls` class to gallery container:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: On their example HTML, there's no `blueimp-gallery-controls` class on the container by default, but now I see they add it using jQuery in demo.js ;) Thx !

Comment: Version 3+ requires the addition of another javascript file `blueimp-gallery-indicator.js`.

I have yet to figure out if it can be correctly imported and compiled with Webpack though.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the blueimp-gallery.css. Set the elements you want shown to display:block instead of display:none.